# GUI tool for reordering Beamer Slides

Tags: beamer, tools, slideshow, software

When I make a slide show,
I tend to just dump out sides without too much concern for order or logical flow.
Then afterwards, I go back reorder them and add any connecting slides I need etc.

I realised today that outside of the LaTeX world,
everyone's slide creation software has an outline pane that shows little pictures.
And you can drag and drop the slides around to get the order you want.

To my surprise TeX Studio doesn't show beamer slides in the outline at all -- only sections and subsections etc; and you can't move them around.
I know LyX shows sections etc and lets you move them around; making corresponding edits in the source.
I've not tried lyx with beamer; but it does illustrate the point that source code can be manipulated in this way (lyx format is at a low level very similar to latex)

I do get that beamer slides are a little more complicated than sections, since you can have referenced things that are outside the slides (like created commands).
But it seems like just separating slides as being from the previous `\end{frame}` to its own `\end{frame}`, would be a strong heuristic.

Moving slides around is something I do much more than moving sections.
So a GUI tool to help would be nice. 
Is anyone aware of one?

Comment: Once you have created the PDF file in many PDF browsers you can, of course, drag and drop the slides to reorder them. Of course, you will have to drag the individual transitions of each slide separately, which is perhaps what you are really asking about. As a random PDF viewer has no way of knowing that certain pages in the PDF file are related I don't think that there is an easy way to change this.

Comment: Once you have the PDF, it is too late though to go and add-in the extra slides that you see you need to connect ideas in the newly ordered slides